# Allow origins in Spring 5.7.3

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, cors

I'm lost with CORS again :(

I followed [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html) and set up my WebConfig like this:

```kt
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig() {

    @Bean
    fun corsConfigurationSource(): CorsConfigurationSource = CorsConfiguration()
            .apply { allowedOrigins = listOf("http://localhost:3000", "*") }
            .apply { allowedMethods = listOf("*") }
            .let { corsConfig ->
                UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource().apply { registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig) }
            }

    @Bean
    fun configure(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors { }

        http.sessionManagement { it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) }

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                "/auth/**",
                "**/demo",
            ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

        http.exceptionHandling { it.authenticationEntryPoint { _, response, authException ->
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.message)
        } }

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)

        return http.build()
    }
}
```

and I still get CORS error, "http://localhost:3000" being blocked. I tried multiple variations, followed multiple tutorials and I just can't solve this one.
Did I make and error that I can't see?

Edit: When I "solved" this I encountered another irrational problem. Apparently the core problem was in editor/browser. After restart everything works as expected.
Guys, if you think something should work and it doesn't, just try to restart editor and browser. It may save you 2 days.

I'm going to add that [CorsConfigurationSource can be replaced by CorsFilter bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#cors()).

- fun corsFilter() : CorsFilter
- fun corsConfigurationSource() : CorsConfigurationSource

Answer (score -1):

It's really strange but after adding **allowedHeaders** to **CorsConfiguration** it works fine:

```kt
CorsConfiguration()
    .apply {
        allowedOrigins = listOf("http://localhost:3000")
        allowedMethods = listOf("*")
        allowedHeaders = listOf("*")
    }
```

I know it's weird because spring doesn't mention allowedHeaders in their docs, but I verified this solution both on my localhost and AWS deploy and in both cases I get cors error if I omit allowedHeaders.

Very good tip is also to check **Disable cache** checkbox in your **DevTools -> Network** tab when testing your cors implementation.

To make it complete, cors can be configured by [implementing of one of two beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#cors()):

- fun corsFilter() : CorsFilter
- fun corsConfigurationSource() : CorsConfigurationSource